# How do I access a datatable and add/remove rows from a chart OUTSIDE the callback-function?

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

I want to use google charts and added the following code to a page

```
google.charts.load('current', {packages: ['corechart', 'line']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawLines); 

function drawLines() {
  data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  ...
}
```

The chart is built as expected, but I cannot find out how to add or remove rows when outside the callback-function drawlines()

I tried defining the variable data in different ways:

**on toplevel:**

```
var data;         // gives me "data is not a function" when used after the callback

google.charts.load('current', {packages: ['corechart', 'line']});
data = new google.visualization.DataTable(); // also gives me "data is not a function"
```

**after the callback-code**

```
var data = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
data.addRow([30,100,95]);
```

**in the callback**
I removed keyword `var` to make data a global var

Nothing worked. Help is very much appreciated!

Comment: For example for adding row: `data.addRows(3)`. [Here](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/examples) are official examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

defining `data`, `chart`, & `options` globally should work fine.

just be sure not to use them until after the callback has fired.

see following working snippet,
click the update chart button to see it work...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {packages: ['corechart', 'line']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawLines);

var data;
var options;
var chart;

function drawLines() {
  data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('number', 'x');
  data.addColumn('number', 'y0')
  data.addColumn('number', 'y1')
  data.addRows([
    [0, 10, 30],
    [1, 11, 31],
    [2, 12, 32],
    [3, 13, 33],
    [4, 14, 34]
  ]);

  options = {
    title: 'Test Update'
  };

  chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  chart.draw(data, options);

  document.getElementById('update-chart').addEventListener('click', updateChart);
}

function updateChart() {
  var rangeY0 = data.getColumnRange(1);
  var rangeY1 = data.getColumnRange(2);

  data.addRow([
    data.getNumberOfRows(),
    rangeY0.max + 1,
    rangeY1.max + 1
  ]);

  chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<input id="update-chart" type="button" value="Update Chart" />
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I now get 'cannot read property draw of undefined' in updateChart()

Comment: Funny, as soon as I copy your code and adjust it to match my html, it works. Thank you!